# omniauth-facebook AuthHash does not have FB email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am playing around with omniauth-facebook to see if I can use it for my future app.

I followed the instructions said in this site, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview, 
step-by-step.

After the app authorisation process, I can't proceed with the login part because Devise requires an email address but somehow the OmniAuth::AuthHash provided to me only contains the 'name' and 'image' fields.

I already set the scope to 'email' and app authorisation part confirms this.

Please help.  thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have setup the scope correctly? Another option is to use `"#{info[:nickname]}@facebook.com"` since facebook email adresses are just `username@facebook.com`.

Comment: Also see the troubleshooting section since users can approve your app but deny email. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#troubleshooting

Comment: Found the fix.  i just needed to add 'info_fields' option to devise's configuration.

```config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'],    FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret'],·
                  scope: 'email, publish_actions',
                  info_fields: 'email,gender'```

Thanks for the help guys. :)